# Change background and font color of shiny widgets

Tags: css, r, fonts, shiny, background-color

I am trying to change the font and background color of shiny checkbox, but it doesnt seem to work out.

```
 library(shiny) 
        shinyUI( 
        navbarPage("First App", tabPanel("A", sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(h5("sidebar") ) , mainPanel(  checkboxInput("add", "Add" )  ) )), tabPanel("B"), tags$head(tags$style("#add{background: #FFFF00; color:#880000  }" ))))
```

Any suggestions to make this work?

Answer (score -2):

For my dashboard i use :

```
tags$head(tags$style(HTML('
#add {background-color: rgba(0,204,204,1); color:rgba(0,204,204,1);}'
)))
```

Comment: hey CClaire, i tried but I couldnt make it work for the check box, i could manage to use the following code and make it work. textInputRow<-function (inputId, label, value = "") 
{
  div(style="display:inline-block; background: #FFFF00; color:#880000",
      tags$label(label, `for` = inputId),
      tags$input(id = inputId, type = "checkbox", value = value,class="input-small"))
 
}
runApp(list(
  ui = bootstrapPage(
    textInputRow(inputId="xlimitsmin", label="x-min")
  
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {}
))

Comment: I'm not very sure to understand, when i execute your code it work
require('shiny')
textInputRow<-function (inputId, label, value=""){
  div(style="display:inline-block; background: #FFFF00; color:#880000", 
      tags$label(label, inputId),
      tags$input(id = inputId, type = "checkbox", value = value, class="input-small")) 
} 

runApp(list( 
  ui = bootstrapPage( textInputRow(inputId="xlimitsmin", label="x-min") ), 
  server = function(input, output) {} ))

Comment: yes CClaire, the code I commented lastly works :) Prob fixed :)